# Photoshop not saving correct dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, save, smartobject

I made a copy of a smart object, and I want it to be `50px by 50px`. When I use the free transform tool the closest Photoshop will let me set it is `49.98px by 49.98px`. I have a couple layers I want to save as individual objects, so I use `File -> Scripts -> Export Layers to Files -> Save as PNG`. But, I think it truncates the number, so the PNG doesn't have a dimension of `50px by 50px`. It has `49px by 49px`.  How can I get a true `50px x 50px` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the pixel dimensions. With the layer selected, hit <kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for the Free Transform tool. On the toolbar at the top of the Photoshop window, right click in the "W" and "H" windows and change from percent to pixels. Make sure the <kbd>Link/Maintain Aspect</kbd> is not depressed. Then just enter in the pixel dimensions you want.

The other option I use is to just create a new `.psd` file with the pixel dimensions I need. Then I drag the layer object I want to re-size, into this new window and scale it to fit. That way I know, no matter what size I start with, or if it's a smart object or not, my window size will always be 50 pixels.